# Iphone преобразует телефонные номера в ссылки. Как бороться?

Tags: jquery, javascript, css

Всем добрый день. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как решить проблему того, что телефоные номера на iphone отображаются как будто без стилей, прописанных для них, а надпись "Телефон" становится меньше. Как бороться с подобной чушью?

Comment: Пример в студию

Comment: @alexsis20102, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем вы видите проблему, как ее воспроизвести и т. д.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@alexsis20102, недавно сталкивался с этим в своем проекте.
iPhone автоматически преобразует последовательности цифр, похожие на номера телефонов в специальные ссылки, кликнув на которые можно совершить звонок.

Пример:

```
<a href="tel:1-408-555-5555">1-408-555-5555</a>
```

Подробнее можно почитать тут: **[Safari Web Content Guide for iPhone](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/PhoneLinks/PhoneLinks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007899-CH6-SW1)**.
Отключить этот функционал можно так:

```
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
```

Или же, что лучше, можно исправить оформление таких ссылок:

```
/**
 * Убираем оформление автоматически добавленных ссылок iPhone'ом
 */
a[href^=tel] {
    font-size: inherit;
    font-style: inherit;
    font-weight: inherit;
    color: inherit;
}
```

**Источник решения - [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/226131/how-to-disable-phone-number-linking-in-mobile-safari)**

Comment: Спасибо, уже сам разобрался, проблема заключалась в том, что записи телефон и прочие находились в див с заданым размером, и, как следствие, iphone пытался их масштабировать относительно размеров блока. Проблема решается, если убрать фиксированые ширину или высоту у блока, причем проблема проявляется именно, если в блоке есть телефоны.